# Weird JUnit logging behavior

Tags: java, logging, junit

I'm noticing some weird behavior using standard logging during JUnit tests.  Does JUnit redirect standard output to a different stream?  How can I get access to that?

Here's a simple JUnit test that demonstrates the behavior I'm describing.

```
@Test
public void logMessage() {
    // set up new logger with output directed to standard out
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my.test.logger");
    logger.addHandler(new StreamHandler(System.out, new SimpleFormatter()));

    // log a warning message
    logger.warning("logger message"); // message 1

    // turn off parent handlers
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    // log a second warning message
    logger.warning("second logger message"); // message 2

    // print somehting to standard output
    System.out.println("standard output message");  //message 3
}
```

Notice that I've created a new logger that simply sends its log messages to standard output (System.out).

Here's the Junit output

```
Testsuite: com.my.FormatterTest
Feb 19, 2009 12:02:33 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
standard output message
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.079 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------
standard output message
------------- ---------------- ---------------
------------- Standard Error -----------------
Feb 19, 2009 12:02:33 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
------------- ---------------- ---------------
Feb 19, 2009 12:02:33 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
Feb 19, 2009 12:02:33 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: second logger message
test:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Why don't ***message 1*** or ***message 2*** show up in the ***Standard Output*** portion of the JUnit output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**krosenvold's** comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566275/weird-junit-logging-behavior/566364#566364) led me to the right answer (thanks!).

It appears as if stdout is in fact redirected to another (JUnit) stream.  The real problem however, was that the the StreamHandler's buffer was not flushed until *after* stdout was reset to its original output stream (resulting in the log messages not appearing in JUnit's output for stdout).  Changing the code to the following gives the right behavior.

```
@Test
public void logMessage() {
    // set up new logger with output directed to standard out
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my.test.logger");
    StreamHandler sh = new StreamHandler(System.out, new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(sh);

    // log a warning message
    logger.warning("logger message"); // message 1

    // turn off parent handlers
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    // log a second warning message
    logger.warning("second logger message"); // message 2

    // print somehting to standard output
    System.out.println("standard output message");  //message 3

    // FLUSH THE STREAM HANDLER !!!
    sh.flush();
}
```

yeilds

```
Testsuite: com.my.FormatterTest
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
standard output message
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: second logger message
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.078 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------
standard output message
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: second logger message
------------- ---------------- ---------------
------------- Standard Error -----------------
Feb 20, 2009 12:58:17 PM com.my.FormatterTest logMessage
WARNING: logger message
------------- ---------------- ---------------
test:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you! I setup a test that outputs to both a log file and the console with a custom. The log file was good but the console kept printing the results out of order. Changing it to a StreamHandler fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

As you indirectly suggest, the junit testrunners redirect stdout and stderr to a separate stream while the test is running. Your logger is normally initialized before this redirection occurs, which means it uses the regular System.out/System.err for logging to console.

This can be fairly easily seen by looking at the source for the JunitTestRunner class.

**Edit:** 
I have looked at some of the source code because your question made me curious. I do not know which TestRunner you are using, and the answer may lay there; the stream redirections etc are not a part of the junit framework but are implemented by ant/eclipse/maven/idea. It *looks* like you addHandler has no effect whatsovever , so I suspect something is intercepting it (your output would be logical if  *all* the logging was done by a parent logger).

Comment: In my example, I'm adding a new handler to the logger pointed at System.out *inside the test itself*.  Why doesn't this also use the redirected stdout set by TestRunner?

Comment: Good point on the JUnit Test runner.  I am using the test runner in NetBeans.  I still don't understand how 2 references to System.out can write stings to two different places in the same method.  That's a head-scratcher for me and is frustrating.